# Django custom form validation best practices?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have a form that contains 5 pairs of locations and descriptions.  I have three sets of validations that need to be done

- you need to enter at least one location
- for the first location, you must have a description
- for each remaining pair of locations and description

After reading the Django documentation, I came up with the following code to do these custom validations

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    location1 = cleaned_data.get('location1')
    location2 = cleaned_data.get('location2')
    location3 = cleaned_data.get('location3')
    location4 = cleaned_data.get('location4')
    location5 = cleaned_data.get('location5')
    description1 = cleaned_data.get('description1')
    description2 = cleaned_data.get('description2')
    description3 = cleaned_data.get('description3')
    description4 = cleaned_data.get('description4')
    description5 = cleaned_data.get('description5')
    invalid_pairs_msg = u"You must specify a location and description"

    # We need to make sure that we have pairs of locations and descriptions
    if not location1:
        self._errors['location1'] = ErrorList([u"At least one location is required"])

    if location1 and not description1:
        self._errors['description1'] = ErrorList([u"Description for this location required"])

    if (description2 and not location2) or (location2 and not description2):
        self._errors['description2'] = ErrorList([invalid_pairs_msg])

    if (description3 and not location3) or (location3 and not description3):
        self._errors['description3'] = ErrorList([invalid_pairs_msg])

    if (description4 and not location4) or (location4 and not description4):
        self._errors['description4'] = ErrorList([invalid_pairs_msg])

    if (description5 and not location5) or (location5 and not description5):
        self._errors['description5'] = ErrorList([invalid_pairs_msg])

    return cleaned_data
```

Now, it works *but* it looks really ugly.  I'm looking for a more "Pythonic" and "Djangoist"(?) way to do this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing you can do is simplify your testing for those cases where you want to see if only one of the two fields is populated.   You can implement logical `xor` this way:

```
if bool(description2) != bool(location2):
```

or this way:

```
if bool(description2) ^ bool(location2):
```

I also think this would be more clear if you implemented a clean method for each field separately, as explained in [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).   This makes sure the error will show up on the right field and lets you just raise a `forms.ValidationError` rather than accessing the `_errors` object directly.

For example:

```
def _require_together(self, field1, field2):
    a = self.cleaned_data.get(field1)
    b = self.cleaned_data.get(field2)
    if bool(a) ^ bool(b):
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'You must specify a location and description')
    return a

# use clean_description1 rather than clean_location1 since
# we want the error to be on description1
def clean_description1(self):
    return _require_together('description1', 'location1')

def clean_description2(self):
    return _require_together('description2', 'location2')

def clean_description3(self):
    return _require_together('description3', 'location3')

def clean_description4(self):
    return _require_together('description4', 'location4')

def clean_description5(self):
    return _require_together('description5', 'location5')
```

In order to get the behavior where `location1` is required, just use `required=True` for that field and it'll be handled automatically.

Comment: I'm sort of newbie at Django, could you elaborate on how creating a decorator would help (links that point me in the right direction would help)

Comment: Actually, decorators are more of a python thing that a django thing.  But, after looking into it more, I don't really think a decorator would make anything simpler than just making a helper method.  I've updated my answer to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can reduce some code. Have 'location1' and 'description1' Required=True (as TM and stefanw pointed out). Then,

```
def clean(self):
   n=5
   data = self.cleaned_data
   l_d = [(data.get('location'+i),data.get('description'+i)) for i in xrange(1,n+1)]
   invalid_pairs_msg = u"You must specify a location and description"

   for i in xrange(1,n+1):
      if (l_d[i][1] and not l_d[i][0]) or (l_d[i][0] and not l_d[i][1]):
         self._errors['description'+i] = ErrorList([invalid_pairs_msg])
   return data
```

still ugly though...

Comment: Make location1 and description1 required=True and you can leave the middle part out (don't forget to adapt the xranges).